# DateInterval is 1 month and 2 days from 2018-03-01 to 2018-04-01

Tags: php, datetime, diff

I have a Convention object with an startDate and an endDate. I want to clone this object allowing to choose a new startDate. Then I'll move all dates of child objects according to this date displacement.

This is what I have:

```
$newDate = $_POST('newDate');

$originalConventionBeginDate = clone $convention->getBeginDate();
$newConvention = clone $convention;

$jumpInterval = $originalConventionBeginDate->diff($newDate);
error_log(sprintf("Original: %s", print_r($originalConventionBeginDate, true)));
error_log(sprintf("New date: %s", print_r($newDate, true)));
error_log(print_r($jumpInterval, true));

//more code adding $jumpInterval to child objects' dates
foreach ($newConvention->getHallReservation() as $newHallR)
{
    $prevDate = clone $newHallR->getDate();
    $prevDate->add($jumpInterval);
    $newHallR->setDate($prevDate);
}
```

The result is, if I clone a convention starting in `2018-03-01` to `2018-04-01`, `$jumpInterval` is *1 month and 3 days*, so, while new Convention is set to start at `2018-04-01` its child objects are set to `2018-04-04`.

This is my log info:

> Original: DateTime Object ( [date] => 2018-03-01 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin )
>
> New date: DateTime Object ( [date] => 2018-04-01 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin )
>
> DateInterval Object ( [y] => 0 [m] => 1 [d] => 3 [h] => 0 [i] => 0 [s] => 0 [weekday] => 0 [weekday_behavior] => 0 [first_last_day_of] => 0 [invert] => 0 [days] => 31 [special_type] => 0 [special_amount] => 0 [have_weekday_relative] => 0 [have_special_relative] => 0 )

I can see that jumpInterval has also `[days] => 31` which seems more accurate than `[m] => 1 [d] => 3`, maybe it has something to do that right now we are in February and this month has 28 days??

What is the correct operation over `$originalConventionBeginDate` and `$newDate`?

Thanks

**EDIT**: Added the `add()` bit to code

Comment: *1 month and 2 days* can be any value between (and including) `30` and `33` days without being wrong.

Comment: @axiac I edited to show the `add()` bit of code, it's not adding 31 days

Comment: Are you interested in the number of days between two dates? Then use the `$days` property of the [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) to create a new `DateInterval` to add (`new DateInterval('P'.$jumpInterval->days.'D');`)

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution, choosing only `days`: `$jumpIntervalComplete = $originalConventionBeginDate->diff($newDate); $jumpInterval = new \DateInterval(sprintf("P%dD", $jumpIntervalComplete->days));` if you want to write it as an answer I'll accept it as correct one...

Answer (score -1):

I think you should be able to fix this just by changing:

```
$prevDate->add($jumpInterval);
```

to:

```
$prevDate->modify("+$jumpInterval->days days");
```